# Tomcat servlet mapping: why does examples directory in url and not in web.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

After installing Tomcat you can browse http://localhost:8080/**examples**/servlets/servlet/HelloWorldExample

Why it isn't 
http://localhost:8080/servlets/servlet/HelloWorldExample

since **examples** is not refered to in Servlet-Mapping ?

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorldExample</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlets/servlet/HelloWorldExample</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Isn't `examples`simply the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**examples** is a context path for *examples* web application deployed on Tomcat. Only for ROOT context you have the same url in servlet mapping and servlet url.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answers:

> Tomcat provides a number of excellent servlet examples in
>   "\webapps\examples". The servlet source files are kept
>   under "\webapps\examples\WEB-INF\classes", together
>   with the compiled classes. To run the examples, start Tomcat server.
>   Issue URL http://localhost:8080/examples.

https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaServletExamples.html